# SQL Trim left with certain character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have thousand records and some of them will have * between 
My goal is to remove everything after * character

```
abc * def
as * sdsdsdsd
dsdsdsdsdsd
rewewewe * c
and become
abc
as
dsdsdsdsdsd
rewewewe
```

My query like this and not clean an anything after * character

```
SELECT  LEFT([Service Term], len([Service Term]) - CHARINDEX('*', [Service Term]) - 1)
FROM [Webdata].[dbo].[WebSearches]
```

Can anyone correct me with this query. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left()`:

```
select left([Service Term], charindex('*', [Service Term] + '*') - 1)
```

Note:  This removes the `*` as well.

If you actually want to keep the `*`, then:

```
select (case when [Service Term] like '%*%'
             then left([Service Term], charindex('*', [Service Term]))
             else [Service Term]
        end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both Substring () and left()

I suggest left () because left is easy

Syntax

select left(yourword, charindex('*', yourword + '*') - 1)